# How can I changed git user password when changing user.name and user.email did not work?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I tried this way:

```
 git config --global user.name “username” 
 git config --global user.email  "email"
```

and then `git fetch` && `git checkout` but no: Git still wants password from
old user's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user.name/email is only about commit authorship, not about authentication.

Check your exact URL with `git remote -v` in order to check if it is an HTTPS one, or an SSH one (`git@bitbucket.org`).
I mention SSH because some time the passphrase of a private key is interpreted as a "password".

If it is an HTTPS one, check your `git config credential.helper`.
Depending on your OS, it could be "`manager`" or `osxkeychain` or ...

If the old user is cached and used, you need to [remove it from the credential helper](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381198/6309), then try and push again: a popup should appear, asking you to enter this time the right user/password.

A good tip when changing user is to make sure that new user login is part of the remote URL:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote set-url origin https://<New-Username>@bitbucket.org/<aUser>/<aRepo>
```